# Count number of words in every div?

Tags: php

I want to go through a web page and count the number of words inside every DIV. How would I go about doing this? I started using the PHP DOMDocument. I am wondering if this is the best approach. Could use some advice on how I would do this. My current code is:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $contents );

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

$pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div");
foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
 // some code to count the text
}
```

Comment: Is this not working for you? You'll have to give us a little more information to decide if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Look at [str_word_count()](http://us1.php.net/str_word_count). This won't handle enclosed HTML tags, though, so will probably need to do more work with your xPath queries.